# How to prevent XSS with Rails actionview helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to sanitize my views from possible xss attacks.

Let's say I have a District object with a field 'name'. I created a new District and set the value for 'name' to `'New York"><img src=x onerror=alert(12)>'`. Now I have a select_tag like this:

`<%= select_tag "event[city]", options_for_select(District.all.pluck(:name), @event.city), { class: "form-control", data: {:action=>"change->events#update"}, include_blank: I18n.t("form.select") } %>`

How do I prevent the script from running when I render the page?

I have tried ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper.sanitize with white listing "select" and "option" and white listing the attributes "data-action", "id", "name" and "class" but still the alert pops up. It doesn't seem to sanitize inside the "option" values.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but please consider this. If District#name is user input (or user generated content) shouldn't you sanitize it when inserting data into database **once** instead of when it's displayed every time?

Comment: Yes, definitely and I am doing that. But according to a security company who made a security audit of the system, best practise is to always html escape. Requests can be interrupted with Burp Suite or similar.

Comment: then you should hire better script kiddies because what they are saying makes no sense. client side injection is a client side security issue, not a backend issue

Answer (score 0):

`ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper.sanitize` seems to remove the javascript code from `'New York"><img src=x onerror=alert(12)>'`.

```rb
3.2.2 :001 > include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper
3.2.2 :002 > sanitize('New York"><img src=x onerror=alert(12)>')
 => "New York\"&gt;<img src=\"x\">"
```

So `alert(12)` should not be called if you properly use `sanitize` I guess.
What about the code below to sanitize each `name` from the array returned by `District.all.pluck(:name)`?

```rb
<%= select_tag 
  "event[city]", 
  options_for_select(District.all.pluck(:name).map { |name| sanitize(name) }, @event.city), 
  { 
    class: "form-control", 
    data: {:action=>"change->events#update"}, 
    include_blank: I18n.t("form.select") 
  } 
%>
```

Comment: This is the solution I also got from chatGPT. I was just wondering is there a way to sanitize everything a rails helper generates.